# Change Terminal 'user@host' colours - Gnome

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal, colors, prompt, ps1

I've pretty much got the terminal colour scheme I want, however the `user@host` colours stick out like a sore thumb, and really don't fit in with the scheme. See screenshot in link:

[image: Terminal Colour Scheme]

How do I go about changing the `user@host` colours (currently green)?
Also, is it possible to change the archive colours (currently red)?

Comment: Edit either your `~/.bashrc` or `.profile` file, or maybe your `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/profile` or `/etc/prfile.d/*` -- somewhere in there is the default settings for `PS1`, the variable that controls the default prompt display.

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: @taifwa - Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for, worked like a charm. And yeah its pretty much a duplicate post, my bad!