# Customise Bash Terminal Font Colours

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors, prompt, bash-history, ps1

A short while ago I asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907170/change-terminal-userhost-colours-gnome) question, on how to customise the bash terminal font colours. The question was answered and I got the colours wanting, using the [link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) provided by a helpful user.

The command I was looking for was:

```
export PS1="\e[1;34m\u@\H : \e[m\[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```

Which gives me the following, in the desired colour:

```
user@host :
```

However, after using this for a while, I notice that my bash terminal is now pretty buggy when recording and accessing the command history. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28827/why-is-my-bash-prompt-getting-bugged-when-i-browse-the-history) thread describes the exact issue I'm having, and the solution being, "use `\[...\]` around the parts of PS1 that have length 0".

I feel like I've tried everything to do exactly that in my PS1, but the history still remains buggy. Can someone please point out what I'm missing?

Comment: try `export PS1="\[\e[1;34m\u@\H : \e[m\[$(tput sgr0)\]\]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These parts of the PS1 have length 0, because they set the formatting (using ANSI escape sequences) but do not produce any other output:

```
\e[1;34m
\e[m
$(tput sgr0)
```

Also:

- You can take out `$(tput sgr0)` because `\e[m` does the exact same thing.
- Put the PS1 in single quotes, so that variables and commands in it are dynamic, not static. (Though it's not important in this situation.)

So you're looking for this command:

```
export PS1='\[\e[1;34m\]\u@\H : \[\e[m\]'
```

Comment: Perfectly explained, and does exactly as I'd requested, thanks for the help!